# How to create an unordered list using React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a list of "tags" that I could use for different pages of my website using react, but the problem I am having is that I need these lists of different tags to be different and editable on each page using it's id, but I'm new to react so I am unsure about how to approach this.

What I have right now is

```
<div className="input-tag">
            TAGS
          <ul className="input-tag__tags">
            <li>
              Tag
              <span> </span>
              <button type="button"> Remove </button>
            </li>
            <li className="input-tag__tags__input">
              <input type="text" />
            </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Just a basic unordered list

I do have the course.id that tells me the id of the different pages, I know I should be using but I'm unsure on how to go about it, any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: I think we may need some more context to better answer your question. Is this in an existing react app? Maybe we could see the entire .tsx file?

Comment: I don't get it, why are you put the delete button and the input inside of <li>? I think it's better to use <li> for placing actual tag names on it and put the button and the input outside of it